# How can I use a marker attribute instead of a marker interface?

Tags: c#, interface

I have read a lot of things about how marker interfaces are bad (or not, it does not seem so clear).

I do not really understand how Marker Attributes work, and I have created a small example to illustrate my issues:

I have an interface to define `Robot`, and an other one to define `Ninja`. It turns out that it exists a class`Foo` that can multiply stuff, but only with the help of someone which is both a `Robot`AND a `Ninja`.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IRobotNinja robotNinja = new RobotNinjaAlways10();
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Multiply(1, 1, robotNinja));
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Multiply(int leftOperand, int rightOperand, IRobotNinja robotNinja)
    {
        return leftOperand * rightOperand * robotNinja.availableShuriken * robotNinja.batteryLevel;
    }
}

public interface IRobot
{
    int batteryLevel
    {
        get;
    }
}

public interface INinja
{
    int availableShuriken
    {
        get;
    }
}

public interface IRobotNinja : IRobot, INinja
{
}

public class RobotNinjaAlways10 : IRobotNinja
{
    public int batteryLevel
    {
        get
        {
            return 10;
        }
    }

    public int availableShuriken
    {
        get
        {
            return 10;
        }
    }
}
```

It is my understanding that IRobotNinja is a marker class: it has no members.

**How can I get the same thing (and in particular, ensuring at compile time that only a `Robot`/`Ninja` will help with the `Multiply`?**

Comment: Checkout generics with constraints `int Multiply<T>(int leftOperand, int rightOperand, T robotNinja) where T: IRobot, INinja`

Comment: Attributes won´t give you any compile-time-safety.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid creating another interface, you can make `Multiply` generic with [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters):

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Multiply<T>(int leftOperand, int rightOperand, T robotNinja)
         where T : IRobot, INinja
    {
        return leftOperand * rightOperand * robotNinja.availableShuriken
                           * robotNinja.batteryLevel;
    }
}
```